# Running Processing Script crashes QGIS3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Trying to create a Python script that processes some data. I'm running this on QGIS 3.01 on MacOS 10.12.6. Having trouble with it as every time I run the below code, it completely crashes QGIS.

All I'm trying to do is run a series of processing algorithms. If I comment out the `processing.run` line, QGIS doesn't crash but also I can't do anything.

```
import processing
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsProcessing, QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink

class testAlg(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('testalg', text)

    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Test')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'test'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(self.OUTPUT, self.tr('Output'), QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon))

    def name(self):
        return 'testalg'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('Test Algorithm')

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        # Commenting out the next line stops QGIS from crashing, but it means I can't actually do anything
        processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', {'INPUT':'/Users/myusername/Documents/temp/test.geojson','FIELD_NAME':'test','FIELD_TYPE':0,'FIELD_LENGTH':10,'FIELD_PRECISION':6,'NEW_FIELD':True,'FORMULA':'( "count" / sum(  "count" )) * 100','OUTPUT':'memory:'})

        return {}
```

Am I doing something horribly wrong in my script or is this a bug in QGIS 3?

--

Edit: By crash, I mean that QGIS freezes and becomes unresponsive. I have to Force Quit it and reopen it before I can do anything else.

Edit 2: This also freeze/crashes Windows 10.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I've made a processing scrip to perform K-Means classification with sklearn. The script works perfectly on my Linux installation, but crashes my QGIS on my Mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `processing.run` in this way:

```
# it'll be sensible to assing the result of processing to a variable
output = processing.run(
            'qgis:fieldcalculator',
            {'INPUT':'/Users/myusername/Documents/temp/test.geojson',
            'FIELD_NAME':'test',
            'FIELD_TYPE':0,
            'FIELD_LENGTH':10,
            'FIELD_PRECISION':6,
            'NEW_FIELD':True,
            'FORMULA':'( "count" / sum(  "count" )) * 100',
            'OUTPUT':'memory:'},
            feedback=feedback,          # add this line
            context=context)['OUTPUT']  # and this line # ['OUTPUT'] is optional
```

When I use in that way, it doesn't crash QGIS. Otherwise, QGIS freezes. (I tried in Windows 10)